# Quickbook-Online PHP integration

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I just downloaded [quickbooks-php](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) from GitHub and setup connection which is working perfect but when I run "example_customer_add.php" page, it doesn't give me any error nor it save data to my quickbook.

**Add Customer Code :**

```
$CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

$Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();
$Customer->setTitle('Ms');
$Customer->setGivenName('Shannon');
$Customer->setMiddleName('B');
$Customer->setFamilyName('Palmer');
$Customer->setDisplayName('Shannon B Palmer ' . mt_rand(0, 1000));
$CustomerService->add($Context, $realm, $Customer)
```

**Output :**
Our new customer ID is: [{-67}] (name "Shannon B Palmer 711")

Do I have to change anything else in the configuration or file location etc. If someone used that code, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're getting this as output:

> Output : Our new customer ID is: [{-67}] (name "Shannon B Palmer 711")

Means that your data *did* get saved to QuickBooks. That `67` value there is the internal QuickBooks `Id` value of your new customer.

First, I would recommend that you make sure you are logged into your SANDBOX QuickBooks account, and NOT your LIVE QuickBooks account. The example by default connects to your SANDBOX QuickBooks account, and will not push data to live QuickBooks accounts without modification (changing `$sandbox` to `false`).

Second, I would recommend that you log out of QuickBooks, or refresh the page, and look for the customer again. If you still can't find it, please post a screenshot of where you're searching in QuickBooks.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working perfect now. Can we use both online and window version at the same time in one website? I mean if I connect both at the same time so data will save in both online and window version?

Comment: You can, yes. Note however, that the code will be significantly different for QB Online vs. QB Windows.

Comment: I am facing one issue of adding note to the customer and below is my code but it's not working.
`$Notes = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Notes();
$Notes->setFreeFormNumber('This is a test note');
Customer->setNotes($Notes);`

Comment: That is completely unrelated to the original question. Post a new question, BUT FIRST make at least a little effort to troubleshoot it yourself. What does the result of `print($Service->lastRequest($Context)); print($Service->lastResponse($Context));` show? Are you getting a specific error message? What error? What does your XML request/response look like? What does your complete code look like? Details details details!